# A RenderFlex overflowed by 265 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, openweathermap

I'm trying to get weather data from the network and show only five indexes of the 5days/3hours API on openweathermap. It works fine when i first run the app but then when i click the Iconbutton button and call the updateUI again it gives me all the data instead of five. Here's my code :

```dart
List<String timeStringData = [];
List<String> hourlyTemp =[];
void updateUI(dynamic weatherData, dynamic hourlyData) {
  setState(() {
    temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'].toInt();
    description = weatherData['weather'][0]['description'];
    cityName = weatherData['name'];
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
      timeStringData.add(hourlyData['list'][i]['dt_txt']);
      hourlyTemp.add(hourlyData['list'][i]['main']['temp']);
      parsing();
    }
  });
}

Row parsing() {
  List<HourInfo> hourTexts = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= timeStringData.length - 1; i++) {
    var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(timeStringData[i]);
    String formatted = formatting(parsedDate);
    String onlyTemp = hourlyTemp[i].toStringAsFixed(0);
    setState(() {
      hourTexts.add(
        HourInfo(
          onlyHour: formatted,
          onlyTemp: onlyTemp,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: hourTexts,
  );
}
```

build method:

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.near_me,
    color: Colors.white,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
  onPressed: () async {
    var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
    var hourlyData = await weather.get3HoursWeather();
    updateUI(weatherData, hourlyData);
  },
),

Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 100.0,
  child: parsing(),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing preparing the data with building the widget tree.

Just remove the `parsing();` call from the `updateUI()` method. `parsing();` will be called by the library when building the tree.

Comment: okay i removed that thankyou, but still when i click the icon button the hourlyDatas shown in the container become morethan 5 and theyre too big for the screen.gives me the same error.

Comment: Do you reset the `timeStringData[]` list when you receive new data?

Comment: yeah i just figured it out!!  had to reset both timeStringData[] and hourlyTemp[] as well, thankyou so much !